# Awk scripting; print not outputting where I would like

Tags: bash, awk

I have an assignment using AWK scripts and I'm having trouble understand why I'm having this issue. Basically I just want to output a simple line of output at the end of my script, but for some reason it's not working.

```
print "Listed are their names (sorted by last names) and phone numbers:"
for(i = 1; i < x; i++)\
       {print "    "topNames[i]"--"topPhones[i] | "sort -k 2";}
print "        Thanks to all of you for your continued support!!"
```

is outputting:

```
Listed are their names (sorted by last names) and phone numbers:
        Thanks to all of you for your continued support!!
    John Goldenrod--(916) 348-4278
    Mike Harrington--(510) 548-1278
    Archie McNichol--(206) 548-1348
    Guy Quigley--(916) 343-6410
    Dan Savage--(406) 298-7744
    Tom Savage--(408) 926-3456
    Elizabeth Stachelin--(916) 440-1763
```

while I would like it to be:

```
Listed are their names (sorted by last names) and phone numbers:
    John Goldenrod--(916) 348-4278
    Mike Harrington--(510) 548-1278
    Archie McNichol--(206) 548-1348
    Guy Quigley--(916) 343-6410
    Dan Savage--(406) 298-7744
    Tom Savage--(408) 926-3456
    Elizabeth Stachelin--(916) 440-1763
       Thanks to all of you for your continued support!!
```

I'm really puzzled why it's not outputting in the order I would like it to.

Also on a side note. What is good programming style (comments and such) for AWK scripting? I'm use to using C++ so I'm not sure where to put indentations and how to align my comments.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to `close()` the sort:

```
print "Listed are their names (sorted by last names) and phone numbers:"
sortcmd = "sort -k 2"
for (i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    printf "    %s--%s\n", topNames[i], topPhones[i] | sortcmd
}
close(sortcmd)
print "Thanks to all of you for your continued support!!"
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html#Redirection

Comment: Thank! That worked. Is there any way I can do that without creating sortcmd and just use the regular sort?

Comment: you could `print ... | "sort -k 2"` and then `close("sort -k 2")`. Using the variable just help to avoid errors with mismatched command names (the manual is clear that they have to match exactly)

Comment: One note: "Dan Savage" would sort after "Tom Savage" if Tom's area code is less than Dan's area code. Try `printf "%s -- %s\n", name, phone | "sort -k 2,2 -k 1,1"`

Comment: +1 to Q and A. Good to know the side effects of not using `close(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the final print statement in an `END`

```
END   { print "        Thanks to all of you for your continued support!!"}
```

From the [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html):

> an END rule is executed once only, after all the input is read

Comment: I forgot to mention that this entire part of my script is in an 'END'

Comment: @JSarwer: You can have multiple `END`s. Try putting this in a separate one (also look into @glenn jackman's answer)